# WPF reset maxWidth and maxHeight to default

Tags: wpf

I have a window app and it updates dynamically, an issue I have is removing the maxWidth and maxHeight set to the window, I must have a maxWidth and maxHeight in some scenarios as per the company requirements but at points I need to remove the max limits for other scenarios.

All I want to know is how to remove the maxWidth and maxHeight, I assume it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` property of a WPF window to `double.PositiveInfinity` which is the default value for both. This will remove any max constraint:

```
//store the current/previous value
double oldMaxWidth = this.MaxWidth;
//remove the constraint
this.MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in XAML, you can do so with the following XAML syntax:

```
MaxWidth="{x:Static sys:Double.PositiveInfinity}"
```

This assumes you have a `xmlns` set up for `sys` as shown below:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System"
```

Hope this helps those who don't want to do the logic directly from C# code.